# vba - looping and renaming files and folders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to rename a folder how has many subfolders and files inside a main folder
the renaming is based to many values and its need to be dynamic (i'm changing films & subtitles names)

my problem is - when the folder name answer the values for the name change the macro can't find a path to continue the loop (if the folder do not answer the values then the macro works fine)

here what I get so far:

```
Sub moviestest()
    Call VideoLibrary("C:\movies")
End Sub

Private Sub VideoLibrary(path As String)
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As folder, f As folder, fl As File

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(path)

    For Each Q In Range("Qname")
        For Each fl In fld.Files

            myMovie = fl.Name
            extension = InStrRev(myMovie, ".")
            myNewMovie = _
                Replace( _
                    Replace( _
                        Replace( _
                            Replace( _
                                Left(myMovie, extension - 1), _
                            ".", " "), _
                        "-", " "), _
                    "_", " "), _
                Q, "") & _
                Mid(myMovie, extension)
            fso.MoveFile myMovie, myNewMovie
        Next
    Next


    For Each f In fld.SubFolders
          Call VideoLibrary(f.path)
    Next
End Sub
```

files name are looking something like this :

- The.something.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mkv
  The.something.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.sub
  Zero.something.2016.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].avi (and many more
  names)

Qname range is somethig like this : 
(named range in excel)

```
 bdrip
 x264
 veto
 heb
 BRRip
 XviD
 AC3
 EVO
 blaa
 1080p
 BluRay
 YIFY
```

this is my first time asking in this forum. I hope I made my question clear as possible
any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are you doing with `Q` ? - you don't use that in your inner loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is hidden in the 4 or 5 nested `Replace` statements.

Comment: @Tim - thanks: didn't scroll over...

Comment: The nested `Replace` statements replace all periods, dashes, and underscores with a white space as well as removing all mentions of things like x264, heb, AC3, etc.

Comment: Nesting the 2 `For Each` statements is very wasteful. All the periods, dashes, and underscores get replaced in the first pass, but then they get looked for  with every iteration of `Q`. No need to search for these things 12 times when once will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is make a function that will return the new name.  This will also make the code easier to read, modify and debug.

```
Sub moviestest()
    Call VideoLibrary("C:\movies")
End Sub

 Private Sub VideoLibrary(path As String)
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As folder, f As folder, fl As File

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(path)

    For Each fl In fld.Files
         fso.MoveFile fl.path, fl.ParentFolder & "\" & getNewMoiveName(fl.Name)
    Next

    For Each f In fld.SubFolders
        Call VideoLibrary(f.path)
    Next
End Sub

Function getNewMoiveName(myMovie As String) As String
    Dim Q
    Dim loc As Long
    Dim extension As String
    loc = InStrRev(myMovie, ".")
    extension = Right(myMovie, Len(myMovie) - loc)
    myMovie = Left(myMovie, loc - 1)
    myMovie = Replace(myMovie, ".", " ")
    myMovie = Replace(myMovie, "-", " ")

    For Each Q In Range("Qname")
        myMovie = Replace(myMovie, Q, "")
    Next

    getNewMoiveName = myMovie & "." & extension
End Function
```

Comment: Thomas Inzina thank you! the code is mach more nice and neat now

Comment: Thomas Inzina thank you! the code is much more nice and neat now
However, I still get an error 53 "file not found"
And it debugs this line (it happens after the new name is made in the function area)
    For Each fl In fld.Files
         fso.MoveFile fl.Name, getNewMoiveName(fl.Name)
    Next
 Is the folder name also change? Maybe this is why it can't find the file

Comment: now for some reason the code removes the extension..
i tried to play with it but no luck..