# Automatically organise files into folder

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am trying to organise certain files automatically into specific file locations. The file types are both .xls and .pdf, and I just need them sorted into specific folders based on a pre-determined list.

For example my list is:

```
----------------------------------------
| Files     |   Directory to move to   |
----------------------------------------
| ABC.xls   |    \Folder1\             |
| ABC.pdf   |    \Folder1\             |
| xyz.xls   |    \Folder2\             |
| xyz.pdf   |    \Folder2\             |
----------------------------------------
```

So I have the file names and extensions and the folder that it needs to move to. Is it possible to have this list in excel and then a macro will search the same path that the workbook is saved, find the file and move it to the new path (and create the folder if it is not already created)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you or someone else please help me to identify the code that will help achieve this?

Comment: You should watch the complete [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) series on Youtube.  This is the relevant one:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 22 - Files and Folders (FileSystemObjects)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHJPliWS9FQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=25).  If you can not get it to work come back and post some code and I'll gladly help you debug it.

Comment: I just edited my last comment, fixing the links.

Comment: My answer to [vba - looping and renaming files and folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025755/vba-looping-and-renaming-files-and-folders/40026882#40026882) should be pretty easy to modify to fit your needs.

Comment: I think I might have found an easier alternative.
I've created an excel list including the current filepath and intended file path. I'll then create a .bat file with "move" and the two directories and the .bat should do the move for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the original filepath (e.g. "C:\file1.xlsm") is in column A and the destination filepath is in column B (e.g. "C:\Data Files\Newfile1.xlsm") you can simple use `FileCopy` to copy and rename the file to the new destination and `Kill` to remove the original.  I think that this is far easier than creating a temp bat file, running it and then deleting it.  You may need to use `MkDir` to create the new directory but you'll have to do something similar in the Bat file anyway.

```
Sub MoveFiles()
    Dim r As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each r In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            FileCopy r.Value, r.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Kill r.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an application, [Sorter](https://github.com/giantas/sorter), which works in a similar manner but without the need of excel or a macro. The application, [Sorter](https://github.com/giantas/sorter), functions by grouping files by their extension ie pdf together but separate from docx. There is also an added option which can group documents together but separate from videos and audios. You can determine the destination of the files and it also has a recursive function which checks into subfolders and their subfolders and sorts/groups the files relative to their initial location. The application is aware of a number of file type, but you can add more. Try it out and see if it can help.